# Creating a bash routine

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, bashrc, .bash-profile

Everytime I log in into my work machine, I have to open a terminal and type the same routine:

```
$ cd /Documents/some_folder/some_another_folder
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant ssh
```

I'd like these commands to execute one after another, by just typing something like `$ initvm`.

I thought about creating an alias for the `$ cd` call inside `.bashrc` but then I thought about doing the 3 of them in 1 function or similar. Thing is I am not sure where to define this:

1. Define the routine in a `initvm.sh` file and `alias` that file inside `.bashrc`
2. Define the routine inside `.bashrc`

Can I get some directions on this please?

Comment: Use a function in your .bashrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply create one new `alias` in your `.bashrc` file, e.g.:

```
alias go='cd /Documents/some_folder/some_another_folder && vagrant up && vagrant ssh'
```

See this answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/756772

Answer (score 1):

Just add those commands to your .bashrc file one line for each command if you want them executed everytime you open the bash .

Otherwise use the answer from SnY and mind the single quotes to have to enter the alias to execute the commands.